# VB.NET ms access query to create a table that includes the format property

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, format, create-table

im trying to create a table in access using vb.net. the table includes datetime datatypes and currency datatype. i need to format the datetime field to "short date" or "Short time" for example. how could i do that in the create table command?

here is my query:

```
dim sqlquery as string= " create table receipt (ReceiptID Counter,
                         receiptDate Datetime, receiptHour Datetime, receiptTotal currency)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot specify field formats in pure SQL. You could use DAO or ADOX an set field properties (including display format) there. It may be possible to manipulate MS Access hidden internal tables to include formats - but this is subject to change between Access versions and is undocumented anyway.

Comment: Access only has one DateTime type.  The 'format' you can specify in the Access UI is just a) how it will display to you in the UI and b) how it would be formatted in an access/vba form

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be a good idea to store the date as short date. Instead you can store the date in the standard datetime format and then you can use the [format function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-the-date-and-time-field-in-Access-47fbbdc1-52fa-416a-b8d5-ba24d881b698) to [format the date](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/210276) in which you want.